# Apache Header edit Location not working

Tags: apache-2.4

I'm trying to edit the `Location` header for responses but I can't get it to work - other headers are editable though

```
# This works
Header always edit Content-Type test TEST

# This doesn't work
Header always edit Location test TEST
```

The `Location` header is being set by a .htaccess file that I can't edit.
At the moment I have the code in the main apache.conf but I could move it into a vhost if necessary.

What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 1):

Can you live with the .htaccess being ignored completely?
Then you could set the AccessFileName to something else.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html

I find it quite strange that you are the server admin but do not have the chance to edit the .htaccess though.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I'm afraid I need the .htaccess. As for not being able to edit the .htaccess, in reality it's not just a single one - there are many websites written by many devs and it's not feasible to get them all updated (and keep updating new ones).

Comment: Okay so what you want is to "overwrite" whatever any of the virtual hosts/websites has manually configured as Location Header, is it? And you want to set the same location for all of them colelctively?

Comment: Yup that's right - I'll actually be editing it to replace `^http:` with `https:` in certain circumstances to fix an issue that's come up because of our load balancer

Comment: I currently don't have an apache to play with but I guess there should be a way through settings AllowOverride to something like "all except header location" but I don't know the exact syntax, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I've not been able to fix the problem the way I set out to, but I have fixed it a different way:

The load balancer is terminating SSL traffic, so only HTTP traffic is sent to Apache.
Originally, this was being sent to port 80 for both originally-HTTP and originally-HTTPS requests.

I've changed this so that originally-HTTP requests go to port 80, and originally-HTTPS requests go to port 81; i.e. a different vhost.

I've used an `Include` directive to share config, and set the `ServerName` to have "https://" in front of it in the port 81 vhost.

#### my-site.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    Include /etc/apache2/includes/example.conf
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:81>
    ServerName https://example.com
    Include /etc/apache2/includes/example.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

#### example.conf

```
ServerAlias foo.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/example/public

LogLevel info
ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/example.log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/example.log combined
```